# How to check for two visually similar images in a directory containing many sub folders?

Tags: windows-7, images, user-folders, simplification

I have a image in jpeg format in a sub folder. I want to check if the same image is present in any other sub folder in that folder. All sub folders have a lot of images. The same image may be present in any other sub folder but definitely not with the same name. What should I do to check if the same image is present in any other sub folder in a folder containing many sub folders with many images and also text documents.

Comment: Would the name of the file be the same, just with a different extension? i.e. `bird.jpg` may be `bird.png`?

Comment: @JaredT It may be or may not be. I have to actually search for redundant images so that I can delete the extra images occupying my disk space.

Answer (score 2):

#### What should I do to check if the same image is present in any other sub folder?

I use dupeGuru for this - it can find duplicates by looking at file contents, ignoring the file names.

> dupeGuru is a cross-platform (Linux, OS X, Windows) GUI tool to find
>   duplicate files in a system. It’s written mostly in Python 3 and has
>   the peculiarity of using multiple GUI toolkits, all using the same
>   core Python code. On OS X, the UI layer is written in Objective-C and
>   uses Cocoa. On Linux 7 Windows, it’s written in Python and uses Qt5.
>
> dupeGuru is a tool to find duplicate files on your computer. **It can
>   scan either filenames or contents.** The filename scan features a fuzzy
>   matching algorithm that can find duplicate filenames even when they
>   are not exactly the same. dupeGuru runs on Mac OS X and Linux.
>
> dupeGuru is efficient. Find your duplicate files in minutes, thanks to
>   its quick fuzzy matching algorithm. dupeGuru not only finds filenames
>   that are the same, but it also finds similar filenames.

...

> dupeGuru is good with pictures. It has a special Picture mode that can
>   scan pictures fuzzily, allowing you to find pictures that are similar,
>   but not exactly the same.

Source [dupeGuru | finds duplicate files](https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with dupeGuru in any way, I am just an end user of their software.

Comment: Can it match for images? Because images do not have contents. They are a set of pixels.

Comment: Yes, see my answer. I regularly use it for deleting duplicate images and music on my data hard drive.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Images have contents consisting of a header and data (representing the pixels).